# AngularJS ng-select use an objects property and its value as options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to use this kind of object

```
{1: 'foo', 2: 'bar'}
```

with [ng-select](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.26/docs/api/ng/directive/select). I've tried all the four options from [the documention](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.26/docs/api/ng/directive/select) it shows for objects but I can't get it to work. I've already searched SO for this kind of question but none of ones I found matches my object.

```
<select ng-model="selectedCountry" ng-options="value for (key, value) in countries"></select>
```

When selecting one of the selects that it shows it is using, I guess the object id or index, but **not** the propety as value. I'm expecting it to get the value 1 when foo is selected and 2 when bar is selected. I'm trying to get the properties as values for the select.

[Plunker example.](http://plnkr.co/edit/M81vuRXMsljMwe5r73cM)

This is **not** a typo. it doesn't work in the desired way even after I've removed the ng- prefix of the element. Check the updated Plunker link.

Comment: Remove the `ng-` from in front of `select`.

Comment: Ahhh! Thank you! If you write that as answer I'll flag it as correct!

Comment: Wait, this is not 100% correct, it is not using the property as value. See http://plnkr.co/edit/M81vuRXMsljMwe5r73cM

Comment: I'm confused, what isn't working here? when you select `Foo` or `Bar` from the dropdown, it outputs `Foo` or `Bar` below.  What are you *expecting* it to do?

Comment: Sorry, I'm expecting it to get the value `1` when `foo` is selected and `2` when `bar` is selected. I'm trying to get the properties as values for the select.

Comment: Use `ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in countries"`.

Comment: Thank you @Absor! That solved it. Is there any page that explains all these expression somewhere? I would like to understand all the different ways you can handle the objects and arrays. Sorry, I wish there would be a way to share the points for the correct answer between you both.

Comment: @Falk, it is in the documentation page that you linked: `select as label for (key , value) in object` where "`select`: The result of this expression will be bound to the model of the parent `<select>` element" and "`label`: The result of this expression will be the label for `<option>` element."

Comment: OK, it was my fault then and I did something wrong... I never excluded that possibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, given `{1: 'foo'}` you want the dropdown to show `foo` in the dropdown, and output `1` when selected.

This option would work:
`ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in countries`.  `key as` sets the output to the `key` element, `value for` sets `value` to the dropdown iterator.